# Scatter plot in Excel using time data for x-y scatter plot graph without converting to data series

Tags: excel, excel-2010, scatter-plot

I have data for the x and y coordinates that are based on time ("hh:mm:ss") for an x y scatterplot for excel. Although I have put the x-axis data and y-axis data in adjacent columns and have highlighted them both when choosing the scatterplot, the excel continues to recognize the data not as x and y coordinates but two independent data series. How can I make the excel scatter plot program recognize the data as x axis and y-axis data points and not data series (independent variables)?

Comment: I've tried what I think you're describing and it seems to be working for me... What are the data types you're using for the x and y coordinates?

Answer (score 5):

Make sure Excel knows the times are really times, and not just text that looks to you and me like times.

Insert a row above the two columns of data. Keep the cell above the times (X values) blank, put a label above the Y values. Select this range including the header row, insert an XY chart.

Answer (score 1):

Change the cell format of the x-axis data to a NUMBER or TEXT before making the chart. When the chart is rendered, change the display formatting of the x-axis back to date/time.